# Vega plot with secondary y-axis

Tags: vega

I'm attempting to create an area plot with a secondary y-axis in Vega. I'm building off of the area chart example shown [here](http://trifacta.github.io/vega/editor/index.html?spec=area) in the editor. I've added a "col" field to the data and am using the facet transform to organize the data into groups with "col" as the key. I've added the secondary axis and a scale for each group but I can't figure out how, when declaring the marks, to map the column of data to the appropriate scale. In other words, I don't know how to have "y" and "y2" in the "enter" property, use scale "A" if the current mark is col=A or scale "B" if the current mark is col=B. Here's the vega object I'm working on:

```
{
  "width": 500,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": {"top": 10, "left": 30, "bottom": 30, "right": 30},
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"x": 1,  "y": 28, "col": "A"}, {"x": 2,  "y": 55, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 3,  "y": 43, "col": "A"}, {"x": 4,  "y": 91, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 5,  "y": 81, "col": "A"}, {"x": 6,  "y": 53, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 7,  "y": 19, "col": "A"}, {"x": 8,  "y": 87, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 9,  "y": 52, "col": "A"}, {"x": 10, "y": 48, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 11, "y": 24, "col": "A"}, {"x": 12, "y": 49, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 13, "y": 87, "col": "A"}, {"x": 14, "y": 66, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 15, "y": 17, "col": "A"}, {"x": 16, "y": 27, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 17, "y": 68, "col": "A"}, {"x": 18, "y": 16, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 19, "y": 49, "col": "A"}, {"x": 20, "y": 15, "col": "A"},
        {"x": 1,  "y": 26, "col": "B"}, {"x": 2,  "y": 59, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 3,  "y": 50, "col": "B"}, {"x": 4,  "y": 94, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 5,  "y": 83, "col": "B"}, {"x": 6,  "y": 50, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 7,  "y": 17, "col": "B"}, {"x": 8,  "y": 81, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 9,  "y": 48, "col": "B"}, {"x": 10, "y": 20, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 11, "y": 20, "col": "B"}, {"x": 12, "y": 80, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 13, "y": 90, "col": "B"}, {"x": 14, "y": 22, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 15, "y": 20, "col": "B"}, {"x": 16, "y": 19, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 17, "y": 2, "col": "B"}, {"x": 18, "y": 4, "col": "B"},
        {"x": 19, "y": 3, "col": "B"}, {"x": 20, "y": 1, "col": "B"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "width",
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "data.x"}
    },
    {
      "name": "A",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "data.y"}
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "data.y"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color", "type": "ordinal", "range": "category10"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"type": "x", "scale": "x", "ticks": 20},
    {"type": "y", "scale": "A"},
    {"type": "y", "scale": "B", "orient":"right"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "data": "table",
        "transform": [{"type": "facet", "keys": ["data.col"]}]
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "area",
          "properties": {
            "enter": {
              "interpolate": {"value": "monotone"},
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "data.x"},
              "y": {"scale": "A", "field": "data.y"},
              "y2": {"scale": "A", "value": 0},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "data.col"}
            },
            "update": {
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
            },
            "hover": {
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

looking for <strike>the same</strike> a similar answer I found your question. Then used your code to play and noticed, that you have nested another array marks within your array "marks". Then I played around in the [interactive Vega editor](http://trifacta.github.io/vega/editor/index.html?spec=area) and found the following solution: instead of using cols "A" and "B" I defined a "z" (using a value closer to 200) and used data.z for the scale "B" . Then added another marks array after the existing and only changed the "field" value of "y". This at least appears to work in the interactive editor.

```
{
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": {"top": 10, "left": 30, "bottom": 30, "right": 10},
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"x": 1,  "y": 28}, {"x": 2,  "y": 55, "z" : 150},
        {"x": 3,  "y": 43}, {"x": 4,  "y": 91},
        {"x": 5,  "y": 81}, {"x": 6,  "y": 53},
        {"x": 7,  "y": 19}, {"x": 8,  "y": 87},
        {"x": 9,  "y": 52}, {"x": 10, "y": 48},
        {"x": 11, "y": 24}, {"x": 12, "y": 49},
        {"x": 13, "y": 87}, {"x": 14, "y": 66},
        {"x": 15, "y": 17}, {"x": 16, "y": 27},
        {"x": 17, "y": 68}, {"x": 18, "y": 16},
        {"x": 19, "y": 49}, {"x": 20, "y": 15}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "data.x"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "data.y"}
    },
{
      "name": "z",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "data.z"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"type": "x", "scale": "x"},
    {"type": "y", "scale": "y"},
    {"type": "y", "scale": "z", "orient" : "right"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "properties": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "data.x"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": true, "offset": -2},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "data.y"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0}

        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },
{
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "properties": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "data.x"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": true, "offset": -9},
          "y" : {"scale":"z", "field": "data.z"},

          "y2": {"scale": "y", "value": 0}

        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "green"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "orange"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks a lot for the question, I learned quite a bit today. :)