# How do I add a secondary, independent Y-axis in Vegas (the Scala DSL for Vega-Lite)?

Tags: scala, plot, vega-lite

I want to plot multiple lines with different scales in the same plot.
This is what I have so far:

```
import vegas._
import vegas.data.External._

Vegas.layered("Displacement and miles per gallon against horsepower").
  withURL(Cars).
  withLayers(
    Layer().
      mark(Line).
      encodeX("Horsepower", Quantitative).
      encodeY("Displacement", Quantitative, AggOps.Mean),
    Layer().
      mark(Line).
      encodeX("Horsepower", Quantitative).
      encodeY("Miles_per_Gallon", Quantitative, AggOps.Mean).
      configMark(color="red")
  ).
  show
```

But it aligns both layers on the same Y-axis:
[vegas-viz plot with two layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlUnO.png)

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610630/how-do-i-add-a-secondary-y-axis-to-my-vega-lite-chart#45720016) I know that in Vega-Lite two independent axes can be realised by adding

```
"resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
```

to the plot definition. The complete example is [here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/layer.html#combined-scales-and-guides).

Is it possible to achieve the same in a Vegas plot?