# How do I add secondary Y axis in vega-lite with 2 series having the same scale?

Tags: vega-lite

I'm trying to build something like this:
[example histogram with multiple independent series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWKyb.png)

I have 2 independent y-axis with orient left and right.

All series/layers using `"orient":"right"` should be sharing the same scale and all series/layers using `"orient":"left"` should be sharing the same scale.

I know of the `"resolve"` option [as documented here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/resolve.html)  but having read this [How do I add a secondary Y axis to my vega-lite chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610630/how-do-i-add-a-secondary-y-axis-to-my-vega-lite-chart) and a bunch of other questions I couldn't find my particular use case.

My futile attempt so far looks like this:
[example in online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-fI7eXCkFghbQ2EahEJZFAtG2u6QD1erCQTLZXL5ZQlMoVSmO0Xi2iShboKheCqBzHBlVh9XwxiIoFYnF4glc9Yk5Nc6j4Fr+QI6RLtKlw2nJkvUMCELI5PIFMDsbOVMDbMDQHraiC9PUHA1Gham80aNYbLYBh3x+2TR3nFQuozXRv3R48qDvL6-f4Bx9V0NquGaqM7m3KB0XPStEx5NFum-fMjAlFUS1GUVDyDJUQwhGt-0jCt42xXFsFbIkO0gLseypPsMGIodqTwUdWgoCcpzTWdlHnRcqhXNdeiAnUQG4sA+g0Kk4MUMRETA9wECicEDFAyBtk0ZAwSURS5X4rcQCAA)
[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Anh.png)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "transform":[
    {"calculate":"datum.Production_Budget * 0.5","as":"y2"}
  ],
  "layer":[
    {
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "bin": true,
      "field": "IMDB_Rating",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "axis":{"orient":"left","title":"# of movies","grid":false},
      "aggregate": "count",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }},
     {
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "bin": true,
      "field": "IMDB_Rating",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field":"Production_Budget",
      "aggregate": "average",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis":{"orient":"right","format":"s","title":"avg production budget in $"}
    }
  }
},
     {
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "bin": true,
      "field": "IMDB_Rating",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field":"y2",
      "aggregate": "average",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis":{"orient":"right","format":"s","title":"avg production budget in $"}
    }
  }
}
  ]
  ,"resolve": {
    "scale":{"y":"independent"}
  }
}
```

I've tried playing with the resolve option:

```
"resolve": {
"scale":{"axisLeft":"independent"}
```

}

```
"resolve": {
"axisLeft":{"y":"independent"}
```

}

```
  "resolve": {
"axis":{"left":"independent"}
```

}

but none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a layer within a layer: the two `orient: "right"` charts in a single layer with a shared axis, and the `orient: "left"` chart with an independent scale:

[vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvSlU3Co2Sx5ilQF91ESHiPolsAGbcjVDMAbQN4dDF4VjEdZDNIbTxWVDoABSNuTVZ4PB4lAH0AIVZNamQ8MAAqMAAGOgBWNSh0WHiAT2lIZwBdNygYtuQjEI0IUAgJqAwjAGt49nRhvsnIZCV4TMYlajNxyYnIAA9dyHYts09WZFUoXzsxTXiASQBZABFC-IAlHS2dm48bUIcRwkAAjqxvLldLkqF1lvtIG1dqN9u50IdGK19JAAnYlHh4mJkL5CQDocT4gBiMDcXxgay2exNSDUIyMR44XwRWDIVyotGQdDUNnCPAgqAbVgEtQCxF4IES8GQgnMX5wuUQZxy7WTfmTPYrAZDEZosaag7TOagiRKOIIwVrDaaP4os2I444s4qHCXa63e6cqCvD7fX7bFkK4HxCFQtWwuL690HZH6C2Cu7IB7xdKZbK5ZRFEplMnpxHC0W0cXxdBULxlWXJ+WKmMq6Hq+1llYYrFupuIvFrQmg9nUfCN-srfyBHTxVoO-seZiU0G16hgQgZLI5PJgdjF8pgLZgaCQLsTXX9y-u6-7JNow1myBWolbTtN1brTYRtOTo4nb0LiMK4AUzbNQRDT4flyCNyRbUFY1VGFGDhe9kyRPs-zAoMkU6Bd3SFEUjDFJVayGYV30nKAoyVRD2wTCc-x7bEwEfP9BxlEdGDHUsqIOacMGHKB53PFYKVIih103PMd2UPcDwqY9T1EsBbxvMs1IvOVulRS9eg0SBiMUMQ4RxBAIglAxUygLZNGQYElDsmVnG1ZwgA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "transform": [{"calculate": "datum.Production_Budget * 0.5", "as": "y2"}],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"bin": true, "field": "IMDB_Rating", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {
          "axis": {"orient": "left", "title": "# of movies", "grid": false},
          "aggregate": "count",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"bin": true, "field": "IMDB_Rating", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "Production_Budget",
              "aggregate": "average",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "orient": "right",
                "format": "s",
                "title": "avg production budget in $"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"bin": true, "field": "IMDB_Rating", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "y2",
              "aggregate": "average",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {
                "orient": "right",
                "format": "s",
                "title": "avg production budget in $"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet! So if I understand it correctly: the domain and range for each axis are shared within each layer. Meaning by creating multiple layers within a global layer group allows me to basically create a multitude of different axis with different numbers of data series. And then by using a combination of axis offset and position I could for example even create charts with multiple y-axis scales on the same left and right orientation.

Comment: I guess not: the domain & range seem to be the same for all "orient":"right" no matter in which layer they are.  Oh well - was worth a try. But thanks for the answer. it helped me a lot.

Comment: Keep in mind that each layer has a ``resolve`` property that you can use to specify whether scales *in that layer* are shared or independent.